# How to override a virtual base class property with a derived class property

Tags: c#

I can't use `override` since the types don't match and I've read I shouldn't use `new` to hide it, so how would I accomplish this?

SearchBase and ResultBase will work for 80% of my entities but a few will need specific implementations.

This main problem I see is when I do use `new` it's all typed during compile time and looks good in the debugger but passing this object to `System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Json()` seems to have a problem serializing it and they come out null.

```
public class SearchBase<T>
{
    public virtual ResultBase result { get; set; } 
}

public class SearchImp : SearchBase<SearchImp>
{
    public override ResultImp result { get; set; }
}


public class ResultBase
{

}

public class ResultImp : ResultBase
{

}
```

Comment: @PranayRana I'm not sure of a better way to implement. I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: You use the ```new``` keyword to override properties... It's slightly different but in the end the same.

Comment: You can do this using Covariance - declare it `public class SearchBase<in T>`.  But I suspect that will only work for the getter.

Comment: i dont think you need that viruatl at all...becuase there is no implemenration ..and after all property should not have any implementation...then suggest please remove viruatl on property ..and if you want to attach any implementation make use of virtual method

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII New keyword does seem to work but the JSon serializer converts all those New properties into nulls

Comment: Why the downvote? Help me understand please.

Comment: @user3953989  Man, apologies.. I didn't even read it all like a ding dong.  You did say that it seems.  I'll look because I'm wondering if there's an attribute that needs to be included. Have you considered using NewtonSoft.Json or are you?  I think even MS recommends it now over their own implementation.

Comment: @user3953989 Not sure why the downvote.. I bumped it back up one for you.  It's a good question and issue.  Ignore the haters.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII ty sir! I'm just using the default `Json(viewModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` call in my controllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this instead:

```
public class SearchBase<T, TResult> where T: ResultBase
{
    public TResult result { get; set; } 
}

public class SearchImp : SearchBase<SearchImp, ResultImp>
{
    public TResult result { get; set; }
}


public class ResultBase
{

}

public class ResultImp : ResultBase
{

}
```

This way you don't need to override anything (nothing really to override here) and you can keep it type-safe.

Comment: Ah this was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!